# How much will Mirtazipine and Buproprion medications cost in Lisbon, Portugal

Tags: portugal, medical

I am considering moving to Lisbon from the United States and wanted to know around how much my medications would cost.

They are:

- Buproprion 450 mg (300mg+150mg)
- Mirtazipine 45 mg

Comment: To a European, it sounds like an odd question. What would be your status in Portugal? How would you be insured? It could make the price question moot.

Comment: Another question is whether those medications are even approved in Portugal.  When I lived in the Netherlands, I knew someone who told me he took Bupropion but that it was only approved for smoking cessation, and that he had a very difficult time getting the doctor to prescribe it for another purpose.

Comment: @Gala I would be on a Shengen Visa (0-90 day tourist), and I would not be insured

Comment: @phoog Thanks for the heads up, that wasn't a scenario I was aware of but I'll definitely take it into consideration now

Comment: As you will be there for a short stay you are probably better off bringing enough medication for the duration of your trip.

Comment: You might be better served on the [travel website](http://travel.stackexchange.com) then, I assumed you wanted to reside in Portugal.

Comment: @Gala Thanks. I want to reside there actually, but I have to figure out things like medical costs. I was hoping to do so before my 90 days on the Shengen.

Comment: @Bryan I think you are approaching this the wrong way. You should first figure out under what conditions you could get a visa. I don't know specifically about Portugal but in many European countries, you will need to apply for that visa from outside the country (i.e. you will not be able to transition from a Schengen visa-free stay to a long stay). And qualifying for a long-stay visa or residence permit might not be trivial.

Comment: On the other hand, if you do qualify for a residence permit medical costs are typically not a problem, you would either need insurance to get the permit/visa in the first place or, if you are working for a local employer, be covered by the local healthcare system (there is a lot of diversity but European states all have an affordable, nearly-universal and/or mandatory healthcare system).